# Python if or statement

Tags: python

```
code = (input("Write a number: "))
print (code)
if code == "1" or "2":
    print ("bad")
elif code =="3":
    print ("good")
else:
    print ("hmmm"  )
```

Output:

```
Write a number: 3
3
bad
```

I'm confused, shouldn't the output be "good" instead of "bad"?

Comment: `code == "1" or "2"` should be `code == "1" or code == "2"`.

Comment: `code == "1" or "2"` is the wrong way to check for two values.  See the duplicate question link at the top.

Comment: Adding to what takendarkk said, `code == "1" or "2"` would always evaluate to `True` since "2" doesn't have a condition it's just True

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of your logic is wrong:
`if code=="1" or code=="2":`

What you originally had (`if code == "1" or "2"`) is understood by the interpreter as asking the following two questions:

1. Does the value in `code` == "1"?
2. Is "2" true?

The second question will always evaluate to True. So the `if` clause will always run.

Comment: just to add on to the answer above, but in your case you can use `if code in ('1', '2')` which should do what you're expecting. all this does is check if `code` is within the collection, in this case a tuple.